# inflating exception during inflating sliding menu

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I'm using sliding menu library by jfeinstein10.
I want to use both sliding menus (left and right).
the menu activity i'm using extends Fragment and the base activity extends SlidingFragmentActivity.
I get this weird exception when I start the app in the library files.
I tried to extends FragmentActivity instead of Fragment and it did'nt help too.

your help is much needed.
I get this exception:

```
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 
18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.scores365/com.scores365.ui.Welcome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityHelper.onCreate(SlidingActivityHelper.java:45)   
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.onCreate(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:22)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at com.scores365.ui.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:41)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at com.scores365.ui.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:85)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    ... 11 more    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)    
06-09 18:22:18.688: E/AndroidRuntime(25121):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: What is configuration of the project libraries? How sliding menu library is added?